# (How much) does it matter which is sorted through first when checking 2 lists against each other?

Tags: python, list, search

I have a list of 800 elements I'm looking for in approximately 50k files approximately 50 lines long each. (These are xml tags with non-generic name - the search is simple so I'm not using Beautiful soup.)

The list of 800 elements is shortened each time one is found.

Iterating through the files,

does it matter which I go through first -checking each line against all possible elements (check line for "spot", "rover", "fido", etc...) or go through all lines checking for one element at a time (e.g. check all lines in the file for "spot", then check all lines for "rover", etc...)?

Or is this all together inefficient? (This is using python.)
I was thinking of:

```
for line in somefile:
        for element in somelist:
              if re.search(element, line):
                  ....
```

or:

```
for element in somelist:
        for line in somefile:
              if re.search(element, line):
                  ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally leave the larger dataset as the one that's sequentially accessed, and keep the values you're interested in, in-memory or as an index of the larger dataset. So yes, it does matter, and in your example, you're looking to scan the file multiple times, which is a **lot** slower.

Let's take an example that each of those files is 50 lines, and you have 800 "words" that you're looking for.

```
for filename in filenames:
    for line in open(filename):
        if any(word in line for word in words):
            pass # do something
```

Since `words` is in-memory and easy to scan, it's a lot better than opening each file 800 times over - which is an expensive operation.

So, I guess I should phrase it that you should be trying to sequentially scan the "most expensive" dataset (which may not be the longest).

Comment: The elements to look for are in a list and that is the longer list (compared to lines) - so I should iterate through them first?

Comment: @Donnied I've clarified - and check out kindall's answer

Answer (score 3):

The big-O notation, which describes the complexity of the algorithm, is the same either way, but if one of your iterables (for example, the file) is both a lot slower to access and likely larger than the other, you should take pains to iterate over it as few times as possible, i.e., once.

Barring that, the algorithm may be easier to write or understand one way or the other. For example, if you want a list of all the strings in a list that match any regex, it will be easier to iterate over the string list first and check each regex against each line, breaking out of the inner loop when one matches.

Actually the whole task can be a one-liner when you iterate it that way:

```
foundlines = [line for line in inputlines if any(r.search(line) for r in regexes)]
```

As a bonus you'll get the fastest iteration Python is capable of by using the list comprehension/generator expression, and `any()`.

Iterating over the regexes first, it is most natural to make a list of lists of lines that match each regex, or else one big list (with duplicates) of lines that have matched any regex, including more than one. If you want to end up with a list of lines that match at most one regex, then you will need to eliminate duplicates somehow (either during the iteration or afterward) which will affect the complexity of the algorithm. The results will likely come out in a different order as well, which may be a concern.

In short, choose the approach that best suits the problem you are trying to solve when performance of the iterables are equivalent.

Comment: I was looking at that. So each file is read in - the question was then whether to look through each line for all the elements or go through all the lines looking for each element. It seems that given the commutative property of multiplication that won't matter so much.

Comment: Added some more factors you may consider.

Comment: I think this is more understandable than my attempted explanation +1

Answer (score 1):

The order of complexity is `O(n*m)`, where n and m can represent the number of entries in your your list and file so it does not matter which way you do first.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. It seemed like a commutative property of multiplcation type arithmetic but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Well, the constant factors can be important... if one of the two sets fits nicely in cache, then loop over the other one with the outer loop.

Comment: @DietrichEpp agreed. The physical characteristics of data-access then comes into picture after the algorithmic complexity.

Comment: In Python, processor cache behavior is rarely a factor since you can't control how your objects are laid out in memory anyway.